# python how to sum odd numbers in a range?

Tags: python, sum, range

I want to sum my odd numbers, so if I enter num=7 or 8 it counts: 1, 3, 5, 7 : Correct, but I want to sum them. So the answer for 7 and 8 should be 16 (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16)

Or if I enter num=9 then I expect 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25

I must use While for this calc.

```
num = int(input("Insert number: "))
sum = 1
num += 1
while sum < num:
    print(sum)
    sum = sum + 2
```

Comment: Why is it a duplicate if OP has to use while?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function like this:

```
num = int(input("Insert number: "))
s = sum(range(1, num+1, 2))
```

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) takes start (inclusive), end (exclusive), and step (In our case: `start=1`, `end=num+1` and `step=2`)

**Output:**

```
>>> num = 9
>>> s = sum(range(1, num+1, 2))
>>> s
25
```

If using `while` is a requirement, then you can achieve the same result with:

```
>>> s = 0
>>> i = 1
>>> while i < num + 1:
...     if i % 2:  # Or: i % 2 != 0, which means we only consider odd nums
...         s += i
...     i += 1
...
>>> s
25
```

Comment: Need to use "while", but your code was correct to my answer. But I need to use While

Comment: @KristenL Just edited my answer to add a second solution using `while`.

Comment: Or  instead of testing for odd numbers use i += 2 in the loop (i.e. `while i <= num: s+= i`). Works also.

Comment: @ettanany it looks like OP might be new here - it might be worth adding a couple of comments to explain what each bit does.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @Petar Done, thanks!

Comment: @ettanany if I want sum like this if I insert number 4 then answer is 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16

Comment: @KristenL You can do something like `num = 4; i = 0; s = 0; while i < num: s += i*2 + 1 i += 1`, adapt the while loop here to make each instruction on its own line

Comment: @ettanany Oh it works.